# Create Jar With External Libraries(Intellij Idea 2017)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I created a simple application using IntelliJ.I exported my project to a jar file and Every Thing was fine and jar file worked properly. Now I decide to use jfoenix.jar in my project for button and text fields.I add a jfoenix to my project and it works fine in the intellij environment but when I export my project to the jar it doesn't work(I click on the jar file which is created and nothing happens). I know my problem is related to the jfoenix.jar library because it seems that it doesn't attach to my project properly but I don't know how to attach external libraries like jfoenix.jar to my project for creating a jar file of the project. Maybe I did something wrong in my steps.

I follow below steps to create jar in IntelliJ:

1-Project Structure->build artifact->select the main class->Ok.

2-Build->Build Artifacts

I check this post "Adding external library to artifact jar in IntelliJ IDEA" but my problem doesn't solve with the solution. If I omit the Jfoenix from the artifact it works properly but when I attach it in the artifact jar file does not work at all.

Comment: `MANIFEST.MF` in `jfoenix.jar` contains some entries which may be required for this library to work properly. When you build a new artifact in IntelliJ IDEA, either this manifest gets overridden with the new one specifying the main class to run, or this file becomes the default manifest (in which case the main class and the dependencies of your app will not be found). This would depend on the order of the dependencies in the artifact configuration. You may need to use some combined/custom manifest for the app to work properly.

Comment: I tried to use your guide in the sample project but still the jar file doesn't work. I uploaded the sample in here  https://ufile.io/vq0h7. I include the jar file in the sample. if it is possible for you  check it and tell me which part of attaching external libraries is wrong.

Comment: In general, I have problem with all of the external libraries that I have in my project and all of the features of them are disable. for example I use Traynotification.jar in my project and like jfoenix it doesn't work in my project. I don't have any clue how to solve this huge problem.

Comment: I've checked your sample project and it works the same if run from IntelliJ IDEA or if run from the command line using `java -jar JarTest.jar`.

Comment: What errors? Works fine for me, you may need to update your system JDK if it's different from the one used by IDEA for this project.

Comment: It works fine when I click run button in the Intellij IDEA and everything works perfectly but when I export it to jar and double click on the jar file nothing happens.As you said I tried to run it from command line but it stops with errors

Comment: Post the errors, the problem is not reproducible on other systems.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Use the same JDK version as in IDE.

Comment: I use Java 8 (jdk8u133) for developing this sample and configure Intellij IDEA to use this jdk but the problem still remains.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas then, your jar works just fine for me in the command line.

Comment: I reinstalled the jdk and problem solved.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was with running on Java 9, [similar to the one reported here](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/365). The solution is to either run on Java 8 or use the Jfoenix jar version built specifically for Java 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You are right.I uninstalled the Java 9 and Java 8 (I had both) and then just installed Java 8 and problem solved after 48 hours.